# Changing mouse cursor in a managed C++ app from within a C++ library

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor, mouse, managed

I have a managed C++ wrapper (for UI purposes) around some C++ libraries. From within the C++ libraries I change the mouse cursor using the Win32 call "CreateIconIndirect()" from a .cur file. This works fine when I use this code in the native C++ app. Though, when used in the managed C++ app the cursor doesn't want to change and keeps showing the default windows mouse cursor.

Not sure what is happening but I assume the managed app hijacks the mouse cursor. Is there a way I can prevent this somehow?

thanks a lot in advance,
Fred.

Answer (score 0):

windows.forms controls usually override mouse cursors, check [Control.DefaultCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultcursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Control.UseWaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.usewaitcursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you need to pass cursor from c++ to c# and set it in winforms application